# Stop interactive prompts from apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management

How do you stop all interactive prompts from `apt-get` when installing or upgrading packages?

I'm trying to write a non-interactive script to install packages on servers, whenever an upgrade requires installing a new kernel, `apt-get` always ignores the `-y` option and prompts me on what option to take to update grub.lst. I always want to install the package maintainer's version. How do I disable this prompt?

Answer (score 32):

You need to specify that you want to use the [non-interactive frontend](https://manpages.debian.org/debconf-doc/debconf.7#Frontends):

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ...
```

With `sudo`:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ...
```