# right way to install packages with apt-get without asking

Tags: linux, terminal, apt, command

Many tutorials do not agree on how to install packages with apt-get without asking.

Some say it's like this:

```
apt-get -y install package
```

And another like this:

```
apt-get install -y package
```

Or:

```
apt-get install package -y
```

What is the right way? (-y). Thanks

Comment: The apt utilties really don't care too much about what order the flags are in, I think all of what you have listed will work, but I've always done apt-get -y (or -dy) install package

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314279/4358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, the three ways are equivalent. This is a general feature of the *nix world: the order of command line switches is (usually, not always) irrelevant. This is the same reason why these two commands are identical:

```
$ ls -l file
-rw-r--r-- 1 chapplec chapplec 100 Apr 18 15:07 file
$ ls file -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 chapplec chapplec 100 Apr 18 15:07 file
```

Or these three:

```
$ grep -i foobar file 
fooBar
$ grep  foobar -i file 
fooBar
$ grep  foobar file -i 
fooBar
```

Basically, when a program sees an argument starting with `-`, it will read it as an option and the position of that argument is irrelevant. This is why [we have the `--`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) to signify the end of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is it doesn't matter for apt-get all the ways are correct although if you use

```
apt-get --help
```

you will get the output--

```
       apt 1.2.19 (amd64)
Usage: apt-get [options] command
       apt-get [options] install|remove pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
       apt-get [options] source pkg1 [pkg2 ...]
```

which says that options should be before the apt-get command, at least according to documents.

Comment: thanks. You're right too. However, I could only choose a single option as correct and I chose the first. Thanks again

Comment: if the problem is solved please upvote my answer and mark it as solved thanks in advance