# Ubuntu - how to bypass whiptail prompts when installing packages from CLI?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I'm automatically installing a bunch of packages in Ubuntu and I noticed that it is prompting for user input via whiptail on the CLI.  I end up killing that process so it can progress, but that actually causes problems with the installation.  I'm running apt-get install -qq .  Is there a way to go with the default options and bypass these whiptail prompts?

Comment: Possibly related: [Stop interactive prompts from apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314279/stop-interactive-prompts-from-apt-get/) (although actually the dialogs are probably from `debconf` rather than `apt-get`)

Comment: Yes, that looks about right, let me try it.

Comment: Hmm, still a no go.  I'm inducing the problem because I've already modified the configuration files prior to installing the application / package.  In any case, I want to keep my version of the configuration file and according to the command line options, -qq should do it.  For example, I'm running: DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq cryptsetup,and I still get the prompts

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314281) hope that helps