# How to avoid prompts with install linux-image-extra-virtual

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, apt, software-installation, package-management

When trying to install linux-image-extra-virtual I get the usual prompt about /boot/grub/menu.lst being modified:

```
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
install the package maintainer's version
keep your currently-installed version
etc
```

In my automated script I am trying to avoid this prompt and get it to default to keeping the current version of the said file.
I tried this which is suggested elsewhere but still get prompted:

```
apt-get --yes -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

How do I do this?

Update: I will try this method: [Stop interactive prompts from apt-get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314279/stop-interactive-prompts-from-apt-get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can confirm that this works:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y install linux-image-extra-virtual
```